# How to add id into onclick event in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi this is my code :

```
window.onload = () => {
    main.makeList();
};

Main.prototype.makeList = function () {
    api.getAll().then(tableData => {
        const tableBody = document.getElementById("tableData");
        let dataHtml = "";
        let idProduct;
        for (let i in tableData) {
            idProduct = tableData[i]._id;
            dataHtml +=
                `<tr><td>${tableData[i].data.name}</td>` +
                `<td>${tableData[i].data.price}</td>`
                + `<td>${tableData[i].data.count}</td>` +
                `<td><img src="${tableData[i].data.picture}" >

                <th <button class="buyButton"  onclick="api.delete(+idProduct+)">Delete</button></th>

</tr>`;


        }
        tableBody.innerHTML = dataHtml;
    })
};
const main = new Main();
const api = new Api();
```

I am trying to add idProduct into buybutton class but, I can not add a variable in this way...

Please show me how Can I repair it

Comment: Follow the same pattern you're using for other replacements, like name, price, count, etc.; `${variable}`. So `onclick="api.delete(${idProduct})"`.

Comment: using `onClick` inline in HTML is not a good practice [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your beginning th tag and end your data string before adding the id variable.

```
<th><button class="buyButton" onclick="api.delete(`+idProduct+`)">Delete</button></th>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to interpolate your value for `idProduct` using `${}`.

```
<th <button class="buyButton"  onclick="api.delete(${idProduct})">
```

Otherwise you are passing `'idProduct'` as a string.

Comment: Don't change the quotes around the `onclick` attribute; they were fine as-is.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I noticed that as well and made the change.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code rewritten:

https://codepen.io/Karkael/pen/VwYyXyJ

```
Main.prototype.makeList = function () {
    api.getAll().then(tableData => {
        const tableBody = document.getElementById("tableData");
        let dataHtml = "";
        let idProduct;
        for (let i in tableData) {
            idProduct = tableData[i]._id;
            dataHtml += `
  <tr>
    <td>${tableData[i].data.name}</td>
    <td>${tableData[i].data.price}</td>
    <td>${tableData[i].data.count}</td>
    <td><img src="${tableData[i].data.picture}">
    <td>
      <button class="buyButton"  onclick="api.delete(${idProduct})">Delete</button>
    </td>
  </tr>`;
        }
        tableBody.innerHTML = dataHtml;
    })
};
```

1. Make sure you understand difference between ES5 and ES6, and please choose only one about to improve readability.
2. Remember to close your nodes like `<th>`.
3. Nodes type `<th>` are using for header cells, never in the body (please use CSS to bold it)
4. Finally remember `node.innerHTML = "<some html>";` is not recommanded, please create nodes or edit them!

After that, I would be happy to become your teammate. :)

Comment: Please don't share code only on an external site. All code should be available on Stack Overflow, with a link as supplementary information.